# Unable to get OpenVPN working on Ubuntu on an OpenVZ VPS

Tags: iptables, openvpn, openvz

1. I have TUN/TAP enabled
2. server.conf

   ```
   port 1194
   proto udp
   dev tun
   ca ca.crt
   cert server.crt
   key server.key
   dh dh1024.pem
   server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
   ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
   push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
   push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
   push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
   keepalive 10 120
   comp-lzo
   persist-key
   persist-tun
   status openvpn-status.log
   verb 3
   ```
3. I am able to connect to the VPN fine from a client machine, but unable to reach any external networks/sites
4. ip forward is enabled in sysctl.conf
5. I am following this guide: http://kyl191.net/2012/09/getting-openvpn-to-work-on-an-openvz-vps/
6. Entering the POSTROUTING rules kills my server's DNS and I'm unable to resolve any domains until I restart.

I think I have all of it covered. Does anyone know if it is possible to run openVPN on an openvz box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this rule fixed it:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0 -j SNAT --to-source $ip`

Woohoo!